# Do I use a quotation mark at the end of a blockquote of dialogue?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, dialogue

> "Sing it to me," said Jane.
>
> I answered, "Here goes:
>
> > Row, row, row your boat
> >
> > Gently down the stream.
> >
> > Merrily, merrily,
> >
> > Merrily, merrily,
> >
> > Life is but a dream.
>
> ---
>
> "That was nice," said Jane.

My question is should there be a quotation mark after *dream* since it is part of the dialogue? The song lyrics are indented in my draft.

Comment: This question will be closed as it is too easy for this site. You can google how to use quotation marks in dialogues.

Comment: You wrote: "Sing it to me," said Jane.  Your question is just like that. The second piece of the dialogue starts with a quotation mark and therefore has to end with one. We **never** only use one mark without another. Why the lyrics are indented on the page, makes me wonder about the source...[I don't make the rules here, fyi.] Also, single marks can be placed around the song. So you get: "Here goes [etc]. 'song in full'". In BrE, it's reversed: Single marks got the dialogue and double marks around the song, if the song is being quoted.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: There _are_ often unmatched quotation marks at the start of following paragraphs within a lengthy quote, but as Lambie says, opening quotation marks always have a terminal closing counterpart at the end of the complete quote.

Comment: @Lambie That would make a good answer.

Comment: Is this a genuine quote from a real text? If so, what? Blockquotes aren't normally used within novels, and there are alternatives, e.g. use italics or single quotes (or in an academic work you would use nested blockquotes).

Comment: @Mitch Yes, but first our OP needs to tell us where she found this.

Comment: Just change ***I answered, “Here goes:*** to ***“Here goes,” I answered:*** [unquoted blockquote follows]

Comment: @Lambie or just interpret the question as "what do we do with  a quote the includes block quotes?" no need for an actual example.